Why does referencing a Nuget package, Newtonsoft.Json, in my library cause a FileNotFoundException in my console app, but not with a local reference?
I'm working on a .NET console application that references an external class library. Here's a simplified version of my code:
LibraryA (LibraryA.dll):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

namespace LibraryA
{
    public class LibraryA
    {
        public static int GetAnswer() 
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }
}

LibraryB (LibraryB.dll):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="LibraryA">
      <HintPath>..\LibraryA\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\LibraryA.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

namespace LibraryB
{
    public class LibraryB
    {
        public void UseLibraryA() 
        {
            _ = LibraryA.LibraryA.GetAnswer();
        }

        public void UseNewtonsoft()
        {
            _ = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}

Console App:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="LibraryB">
      <HintPath>..\LibraryB\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\LibraryB.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

var lib = new LibraryB.LibraryB();

lib.UseLibraryA();

Console.WriteLine("Use Library A.");

lib.UseNewtonsoft();

Console.WriteLine("Used Newtonsoft.");

These are three separate projects. Library A's DLL was added as a dependency to Library B by right-clicking on Dependencies, selecting Add Project Reference, and then browsing to Library A's DLL. NuGet was used to add Newtonsoft.Json as a package dependency in Library B.
For the console app, only Library B's DLL was added as a dependency, without adding Library A or Newtonsoft.Json. When running the console app, UseLibraryA() works fine, but UseNewtonsoft() fails with the error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Why does UseLibraryA() work fine, but UseNewtonsoft() fail?

Can you provide the csproj files?

@shingo added csproj files as requested.

If you add LibraryB as a project reference, the build system will automatically copy Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the output folder of the console app. But since you add LibraryB as a DLL reference, you have to resolve the dependencies manually. (e.g. copy dll files in post-build event)

This error stems from incorrect project references within a Visual Studio C# solution. You can add project references as dependencies, and if you require a standard library, it's better to install it via NuGet rather than adding it as a dependency.
I have resolved the issue and uploaded the project as a zip file.
The output is like this.
Use librayA
Used Newtonsoft.

Stackoverflow-Solution-1

It looks like your solution is to link directly to a Newtonsoft.Json.dll file.
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL"><HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath></Reference>
Can you explain why that works?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
